# How to Combine two sox -m commands

Tags: sox

Is it possible to combine these two sox commands into one (thereby getting rid of the temp file)? Thanks.

`sox -m 1.flac 2.flac tmp.flac reverse`

sox -m tmp.flac 3.flac final.flac reverse

Comment: Have you tried a FIFO yet?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with this:

```
sox -m 1.flac 2.flac 3.flac final.flac reverse
```